# can I delete previously installed instance on mingw now that i have msys2?

Tags: c++, windows, mingw, codeblocks, msys2

I am attempting to learn c++ programming. I am writing these programs on Windows Vista using the Codeblocks IDE, but since I was to learn Linux, I would like to learn to write my programs with as much portability as I can.

I already downloaded the mingw compiler to use with Codeblocks, but while trying to download the GTK dependencies to try playing around with GUI, I downloaded msys2. I noticed that this program also has you to download Mingw32 and or mingw64. Are these packages complete enough that I can delete my previous instance of mingw, or do I need to keep the other mingw package that I had already downloaded in order to compile and run my programs?

Comment: MSYS and MinGW ccontains different parts of the same environment.

Comment: MSYS and MSYS2 are different, so I suggest editing your title to make it clear you are talking about MSYS2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, MSYS2 is a complete development environment with a package manager, compilers, and build tools.  You do not need to have any kind of external tools installed in order to develop portable C++ code with MSYS2.

Keep in mind that MSYS2 supports three different subsystems.  You select which subsystem to use when you click on one of the three shortcuts in the start menu for starting a shell.  The Win64 and Win32 shells, and their compiler toolchain packages `mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain` and `mingw-w64-i686-toolchain`, allow you to write native Windows applications that just depend on a few runtime DLLs.  The MSYS2 shell allows you to write applications that depend on msys-2.0.dll, which is a fork of Cygwin that provides better emulation of POSIX (so programs designed for Linux are more likely to work).  If you want your code to be portable, I think you want it work in all three of those environments.  You can also use VirtualBox or VMware to install Linux on your machine and develop your code in a virtual machine.

Comment: well, I the only reason that I downloaded MSYS2 was for GTK. I do use Linux virtual machines for compiling and checking my programs in that environment, and I really have no need for actually developing apps with MSYS2. With that being said, the IDE I use is having a hard time linking to the GTK library that I installed through pacman. I used "pacman -Ss  gtk3" and downloaded every package listed. but either I haven't downloaded the right packages, or the downloaded files aren't in a format that my IDE expected.

Comment: You could post that as a second question.  Just be sure to give concrete details about how you set up your development environment and exactly what error you are getting so that someone else would be able to either reproduce your problem or see what you did wrong.

Comment: ok, thank you. I wasn't sure whether or not the question warranted a second post, or if it would essentially be seen as a follow up question.

Comment: One package that is missing IMHO is the Tex package (was included in msys)

Answer (score 0):

Find gcc in your msys-git directory and you'll know. Normally, it is missing and in this case, you should keep your full mingw setup. Also, if you want an real linux emulation, use cygwin, not mingw wich just provide a compiler (but not the Linux syscalls etc.)

Comment: In c:\msys64 there is are both mingw32 and mingw64 directories, but the subdirectories are different than those found in my c:\mingw folder which was the reason for my confusion.

Comment: Have you gcc.exe under c:\msys64\mingw32 or c:\msys64\mingw64 ? (perform a search because it may be under a sub-folder ...)

Comment: As for actually learning Linux, I'm using a couple of different live environments for that. One is an older install that came with the book "Hacking: The art of exploitation". I've also got an older version of Kali Linux, Backtrack 5. The reason I'm using the older distributions is that I've got some a couple of books catered to those specific versions. the msys install was basically the only way I could find to download GTK

Comment: So you're safe to use this instance of gcc. That's not "the better option", but an acceptable option like any other.

Comment: Now about GTK, cygwin is the only true emulation of linux. If you have cygwin and have installed apt-cyg, then apt-cyg install gtk+ will install GTK, just as with apt-get if you're familiar with ubuntu. You can also install package from the cygwin setup program.

Comment: good. with all the various things I have on my computer, real estate is sort of at a premium, so I just wanted to make sure that I didn't have too many unnecessarily redundant programs running. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Thank you again, I'll definitely check out cygwyn as well. anything that will help to push my knowledge farther is a bonus.